# PostScript, can't see visual output with ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, eps

```
%!
/Times-Roman 12 selectfont
100 100 moveto
(Hello) show
```

How can I take the output as PDF and EPS
formatted file.

Comment: you might add `showpage` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

Your question really needs some editing, its not clear (to me anyway) what your problem is.

You say 'PostScript, can't see visual output with Ghostscript' as the title, and then want to know about 'taking the output'. So which is it ? A problem viewing a PostScript file when using Ghostscript ? Or a problem with the output ?

You can use the eps2write device to get EPS output and the pdfwrite device to get PDF output, as per the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Devices.htm). Neither has 'visual output'.